# Loading HTML dynamically using JavaScript (class.js)

Tags: javascript, dom-events, javascript-framework

I am working on building an application which has a few HTML components.

#### Use Case:

I am trying to achieve something similar what is present [here](http://tantaman.github.com/Strut/web-dist/index.html#). I want to call the HTML components on click of a menu and apply some actions like **drag and resize**, etc.

#### Research:

I was advised to take an object-oriented approach for building the application and hence while going through Google came across [class.js](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/) for JavaScript inheritance.

I went through the initial tutorials, but I am not sure how and where can I store the HTML initially that will hold the structure for the HTML components?

In the reference application they have used backbone.js and require.js, but I am a bit short on time to learn these.

#### My Work So Far:

What I have tried is creating a file `components.js` and creating the outer HTML structure for a component like this:

```
var textBox = '<div class="structure-textBox">
               <div class="editable">
                <p><span style="font-size:20px;"><span style="font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"><strong>Text Box</strong></span></span></p>
                <ol>
      <li><span style="font-size:14px;">Double Click on the <strong>Text Box</strong> to Edit Text.</span></li>
      <li><span style="font-size:14px;">For easy use of the text editor click on the "i" (to the left of the x close) and watch a 30 sec video tutorial.</span></li>
    </ol>
    <p><span style="font-size:14px;"><span style="color:#7cba0c;">Enjoy web designing with GoBiggi.</span></span></p>
    <p><span style="font-size:14px;">Click on the <a href="#."><strong><u>Design Assistance</u></strong></a> link for further help.</span></p>
  </div>
</div>';
```

This is a text box stored in a JavaScript variable that I want to add when user clicks on a menu. But how can it be achieved using class.js's inheritance pattern?

I have a canvas page created and menus for the components. Now I am stuck at this part of getting the html content and displaying it on the canvas.

Comment: DOM injections have little to do with inheritance patterns, you should start reading about manipulating DOM and possibly consider using a framework like jQuery.

Comment: Try KnockoutJS. It is easy to set up and start with and you won't need to fiddle with HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see that what you're asking has anything to do with inheritance.

There are several simple ways to put something on your web page using JavaScript.

For instance, if you have the following on your page somewhere `<div id='target'></div>`, you could write this:

```
var textBox = '<div class="structure-textBox">
               <div class="editable">
                <p><span style="font-size:20px;"><span style="font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"><strong>Text Box</strong></span></span></p>
                <ol>
      <li><span style="font-size:14px;">Double Click on the <strong>Text Box</strong> to Edit Text.</span></li>
      <li><span style="font-size:14px;">For easy use of the text editor click on the "i" (to the left of the x close) and watch a 30 sec video tutorial.</span></li>
    </ol>
    <p><span style="font-size:14px;"><span style="color:#7cba0c;">Enjoy web designing with GoBiggi.</span></span></p>
    <p><span style="font-size:14px;">Click on the <a href="#."><strong><u>Design Assistance</u></strong></a> link for further help.</span></p>
  </div>
    </div>';
document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = textBox;
```

For best results, I would suggest learning to use a library like jQuery.  These tools are designed to make it easier to manipulate the HTML of the page, among other things.

Comment: thanks for inputs I have knowledge of jQuery and JavaScript but,the system I am trying to build is complex.So I wanted to separate the parts into different JavaScript classes(functions).also I will be handling multiple instances of the same component,so dynamic id's to keep the components unique would come into picture.i need some help on how to approach the scenario

Comment: Sorry if the question wasn't clear enough!!!But just to make things clear i had added reference to a similar website.

Comment: As long as we're talking about inheritance, are you aware of JavaScript's "prototype" inheritance?

Comment: I know nothing about class.js at this time.  However, I would like to tell you about how I deal with HTML objects in my application.

Usually, if there is an object in my application that I only want to show at a certain time, I put the markup of that object in a section of the web page that doesn't display.  When I want it to show, I then move it to the part of the page that does display.  That way, there is no HTML code in my JavaScript. (It provides for clean separation of concerns. To make it even cleaner, I use ASP.net MVC)

Comment: Not much about prototype inheritance,but had a read about it while I was carrying out study.Do you mean you use 'display:block' and 'none' to hide show elements?thanks

Comment: Yes, I do use 'display:block' and 'none'.  Usually via the `jQuery.show` and `hide` methods.

Comment: Thank you for the inputs and help.The structure I want to build is a bit complex and it requires some pre thinking about how things would be handled.If you went through the [link](http://imcreator.com),you will get an idea what I want exactly I am looking for.Also,I believe using an inheritance model would reduce the development time and also help in maintaining the code easily.Your views